# How can I add pagination on my ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building a mobile app from my WordPress website I am getting the content from my WordPress website but I don't know how to load more data to the page

Here is my html code:

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of getData">{{item}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>      
       <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll> 
 </ion-list>
```

Here is my ts file:

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import {  NavController, NavParams, Item } from 'ionic- angular';
   import { Api, Items } from '../../providers';
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
     @IonicPage()
     @Component({
        selector: 'page-latest',
        templateUrl: 'latest.html',
    })
    export class LatestPage {
        currentItems: Item[];
        item: any;
        getData: Object;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, toastCtrl: ToastController, 
 public api:Api, navParams: NavParams, items: Items,public 
  http:HttpClient) 
 {   
    this.api.getPosts().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data)
    this.getData = data
  })
 }
    doInfinite(infiniteScroll: any) { 
    this.api.getPosts().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data)
    this.getData = data
 })
   infiniteScroll.complete()
  }
    openItem(item){
    this.navCtrl.push('ItemDetailPage', {
    itemName: item
   });
  }
 }
```

I need the data to be displayed when we scroll down.

Comment: Will infinite scrolling work ?

Comment: I did try but it dint

Comment: @princes why infinite scroll didn't work? Can you share what have you tried for implementing infinite scroll?

Comment: I just added the code which I found on stackoverflow

Comment: @princes I meant will the functionality of infinite scroll work instead of pagination.

Comment: I have updated my code, Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination doesn't really work on a mobile app. The popular replacement for that, is to use an inifnite scroll.

It works by adding a HTML element on your display. You first fetch a batch of records to display ( let's say 50 ) & when the user reaches to the end of these records, infinite scroll gets triggered, you fetch the next 50 records from the server & display.

The fetching of data is done by adding the parameters `limit` & `offset` to your api call.

```
data; //data to display

getData(limit, offset) {
    this.http.get(API_URL"+&limit="+limit+"&offset="+offset,{}).subscribe((response) =>{
        this.data.push(response);
    }
}

doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    //Calculate your limit & offset values
    this.getData(this.limit, this.offset);
    infiniteScroll.complete();
}
```

This [tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-scroll-performance/) might be helpful for your particular case.